# finding the selected row

Tags: datamodel

I found the following example in core JSF book, this example use data model to finding the selected row then delete it.

But i found an error in this line names.remove(nameToDelete);

can you help me how can i solve this?

```
package com.jsf.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.model.ArrayDataModel;
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;

public class TableData implements Serializable {

    private static final Names[] names = new Names[] {
        new Names("William", "Dupont"),
        new Names("Anna", "Keeney"),
        new Names("Mariko", "Randor"),
        new Names("John", "Wilson")
    };

    private DataModel<Names> model = new ArrayDataModel<Names>(names);
    public DataModel<Names> getNames() { return model; }


    public String deleteRow() {
        Names nameToDelete = model.getRowData();
        names.remove(nameToDelete);
        return null;
    }
}
```

thanks all

Comment: What is the error that it gives? The first thing that I can think of is that you're not calling setRowIndex(int index), so getRowData may return null.

Comment: the error it gives is"can't invoke (Names) on the array type Names. when you write this line "names.remove(nameToDelete)" the red line appear under this statement .

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `remove()` on names, an array of Names. Arrays do not have the remove function specified - you want to call it on model.

Comment: can you tel me how can i call remove() on model ?

Comment: I have found a solution to my problem by using List instead of Array and it is work  here http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html i found the solution thank you  BalusC and purtip31